# Extend enum with additional values

Tags: c, enums

What is the common practice for extending an `enum` in C? I have `enum`s from other includes and would like to extend them with a few values. Hopefully, the following example provides the intuition for what I would like to achieve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <assert.h>

enum abc { A, B, C, };     /* from some other include */
enum def { abc, D, E, F }; /* extend enum from other include */

struct thing_s {
    enum def kind;         /* use extended enum */
    union {
        unsigned n;
        char c;
        char *str;
    } data;
};

void print_thing(struct thing_s *t) {
    switch (t->kind) {
        case A:
            fprintf(stdout, "%ul\n", t->data.n);
            break;
        case B:
        case C:
        case D:
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", t->data.str);
            break;
        case E:
        case F:
            fprintf(stdout, "%c\n", t->data.c);
            break;
        default:
            assert(0);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct thing_s t;
    t.kind = A;
    t.data.n = 1;

    print_thing(&t);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This doesn't compile with "duplicate case value" errors, which I understand because `abc` is being treated as the first value so it ends up with duplicate integer values for the different symbols.

Comment: The reason you are getting that error is because both cases B and D are the same enumerated value (1). Thus the case labels are not unique.

Comment: @MFisherKDX yea, thanks, I understood the error, I was just missing the obvious solution

Comment: How does that union even make any sense? Are you trying to code some icky "variant"?

Comment: @Lundin I don't understand your question, it was just a quick example. The actual code is a union of structs with data corresponding to enum values.

Comment: Yes that's known as a "variant" and is usually frowned upon for many reasons. For the purpose of type-generic programming, it is more common, safe and memory-efficient to use the enum together with a `void*` to the data instead and keep it allocated outside the struct.

Comment: @Lundin Ah, didn't know it was called that. memory efficiency isn't a concern for me, and it's just simpler to not have to cast everything. Its local variable anyway in main

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your only concern is for the integral constants to be unique. Simply assign the first element of your second `enum` to the last element of your first `enum` plus one.

```
enum abc { A, B, C, };     
enum def { D = C + 1, E, F };
```

Comment: Rather: `enum abc { A, B, C, n }; enum def { D=n, E, F };` so there's no tight coupling between the constant `C` and `def`. To keep the last item in an enum as a counter rather than a constant is common practice.

Comment: @Lundin's comment transform `enum abc` from a 3 possible values enum into a 4 one! Not sure it is good design to include a dummy `n` value that should not possibly be used in the context of `abc`.

Comment: @PatrickAllaert It's very common; almost every enum has a counter variable at the end. Another massive benefit is that they can be used to ensure integrity between an enum and a look-up table with named indices. Suppose you have `const int TABLE [n] = ...` - now you can `_Static_assert(sizeof(TABLE) / sizeof(*TABLE) = n, ...`. Rugged, readable, safe.

Comment: But if you're checking for coverage, you run into an issue with `switch` statements where you now have to account for `case abc::n` every time, and `n` isn't even really valid there.