# Extend enum with additional values (follow up question)

Tags: c, enums

This is kind of a follow up question to [Extend enum with additional values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361893/extend-enum-with-additional-values/50361942#50361942). Since gcc version 11 the solution suggested there (which I consider the common practise in C) gives compiler warnings when `-Wall` is applied like this:

```
enum abc { A, B, C, };
enum def { D = C + 1, E, F };

int
foo(enum def bar)
{
    if (bar == A) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The warning reads as follows:

```
warning: comparison between 'enum def' and 'enum abc' [-Wenum-compare]
```

Obviously you can get rid of the warning by using an explicit cast:

```
\\ ...
if (bar == (enum def) A) {
\\ ...
```

Here the actual question(s):

- Is there a more convenient way?
- Is the suggested pattern for extending enums the right thing to do after all?

**Edit:** In connection with a `switch` statement I don't see a simple way (like using a cast) to get rid of warnings:

```
int
foo2(enum def bar)
{
    switch (bar)
    {
        case A:
            return 0;
        case D:
            return 1;
        default:
            return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the warning give you the answer?

Comment: No, it is the correct way.

Comment: Bu I do not understand why you want to do it.

Comment: To me this sounds like an XY problem. Why are you doing this. What is the real problem that you try to solve.

Comment: Why I found a reason to want that is a completely different story. It certainly wasn't my first choice. But the question was not about an alternative design pattern. Maybe I should have started with: "Assume that for some reason I have to ..."

Comment: Ok, about the context: I used that in a C compiler. Enums are used for node types, expressions types, etc.

Comment: @MichaelLehn That's exactly what the XY problem is about... I think I need to do "____" to solve my problem.... but you really need something completely different.

Comment: Your `enum def` doesn't have an `A` so asking for an `A` is just wrong.

Comment: Are you kidding me? You really think I don't know about the design issues with this design patterns? Extending enums in C is a well-known problem and the way how it was solved above is not uncommon. The problems that come with this solution are also well-known. That's why in C++ extending enums became part of the language. Using C one either has to do this manually which means you also have to pay for it with responsibility. The fact that C++ allows to extend enums also is a sign that it is a common problem by the way.

Comment: `why in C++ extending enums became part of the language` Could you kindly give a reference to that? I do not know what you mean. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804840/extending-enums-in-c answer your question? `enums in C is a well-known problem and the way how it was solved above is not uncommon` Could you give an example? Typically in C you put each enum value in a namespace, so it would be `enum abc { ABC_A, ABC_B, ABC_C }; enum def { DEF_A = ABC_A, DEF_B = ABC_B, .... etc.}`. Polluting global namespace with duplicated enum elements sounds like a bad practice and spagetti code.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more convenient way?

Yes, avoid contrived solutions with dependencies between various types.

In theory you could create a `union` between the two enum types if you know that they have the same size and that their constant values correspond. But that's a rather questionable and likely needlessly complex solution.

> Is the suggested pattern for extending enums the right thing to do after all?

Probably not. Ideally each enum will be self-contained with all the constants it is using. So ideally:

```
enum def { DEF_A, DEF_B, DEF_C, DEF_D, DEF_E, DEF_F };
```

The lack of a tight coupling between `def` and `abc` is not a bad thing - it isn't obvious that changes to `abc` should silently and automatically change `def` too - that's rather a potential source for subtle bugs.

If necessary, one can create conversion routines from one enum type to another.